# How to find the rank of a Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank, toeplitz-matrices

Is there any trick to compute or estimate the rank of a Toeplitz matrix?

Or is this still unknown for a general Toeplitz matrix?